# Limit to send push notification to a device

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am implementing **push notification** in my app. It was working fine. Right now i am testing this on my development profile. After few times i send **push notification** to my device, server stops sending any more **push notification**. I tried searching but can't find anything about the limit. How many times can we send push notification to a particular device token on **development** as well as **distribution** profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notification message size is 256 bytes or below you can send notification number of times .

Comment: Message size is less than that only.... But after some 20-25 notifications, i am not getting any more notification on my device.

Comment: It started working again after some 1 hr or so,.... not this time only but noticed this some 3rd or 4th time. Neways, thank you for explaining :)